# Typescript keyof object doesnt get refined and gives TS2367

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a function to validate that a key of an object is a string and its not empty.

```
export const validateRequiredString = <T>(
  obj: T,
  key: keyof T & (string | number)
): void => {
  if (typeof obj[key] !== "string") {
    throw new Error(`${key} is not a string`);
  }
  if (obj[key] === "") {
    throw new Error(`${key} is empty`);
  }
};
```

but cannot work out why it wont let me write this

```
file.ts:8:7 - error TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'T[keyof T & (string | number)]' and 'string' have no overlap
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just worked it out.

```
export const validateRequiredString = <T>(
  obj: T,
  key: keyof T & (string | number)
): void => {
  const v = obj[key];

  if (!(typeof v === "string")) {
    throw new Error(`${key} is not a string`);
  }
  if (v === "") {
    throw new Error(`${key} is empty`);
  }
};
```

Having stored `v`, the type narrowing works.